# SyslogAppender for log4esp

Tags: esp8266, print, logging

I'd like to "merge" two Arduino libraires, namely [log4Esp](https://github.com/hunsalz/log4Esp) on one side and [Syslog](https://github.com/arcao/Syslog) on the other, hence creating a syslog appender for log4esp.

My problem is that log4esp's Appender prototype expects a method to return an instance of `Print` to which it'll write the message.

Syslog can't be used in this way.

**==> Question :** How to create a "Print buffer" / where can I find which class extends `Print`?

Comment: Cerber, question for you https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/58502/library-mixing-log4esp-syslog-for-esp8266

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class `Print` is a base class of Arduino streaming. `Stream` is a derived class and adds reading capability. `Print` has only one abstract method `write` to write one byte to output or buffer. It is easy to [implement a derived custom class.](https://github.com/jandrassy/StreamLib/tree/master/src)

The classes derived from Stream are classes for hardware and software serial like HardwareSerial for Serial singletons and different software serial implementations. From Stream is derived class File of the SD and SPIFFS library, TwoWire class for Wire singleton object, etc.

Class Client is derived from class Stream and is a base class for Arduino standard TCP networking. Examples of derived classes are EthernetClient, WiFiClient. For UDP, class UDP is derived from Stream, of course with implementations like EthernetUDP, WiFiUDP.

You can see this in the source code in local source file folders or in GitHub repositories.

[image]

Comment: perfect answer, very clear ! Thanks @juraj