# How to Create a reference to an External Print object

Tags: serial, arduino-mega, lcd, library

Right now I have an object:

```
class Dog
{
  public:
    Dog(uint8_t I2c, Stream& feedback);
    void Speak();
  private:
    uint8_t _I2c;
    Stream& _output;
};

Dog::Dog(uint8_t I2c, Stream& feedback):_output(feedback),_I2c(I2c){}

Dog::Speak(){
_output.println("Hi There.");
}
```

That is currently constructed in my sketch via:

`Dog Dug([I2cPort], Serial);`

How can I modify my class so that to be compatible with taking either a Serial object or an LCD display (using [Adafruit's RGB LCD library](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit-RGB-LCD-Shield-Library) )?

Eg:

```
Adafruit_RGBLCDShield lcd = Adafruit_RGBLCDShield();
Dog Dug([I2cPort], Serial);
Dog Sam([I2cPort], lcd);
```

Additional info:

The LCD in question is mostly used as a UI display in its own library this library refreshes the display every 1.5 sec. As information from `speak();` and the UI have similar priority, it is acceptable if one instantly overwrites the other.

I am open to solutions that involve modifying the construction of `Dog` the only requirement is that I need to be able to indicate `print("[something]");` in the Dog.cpp

I'm interested in asking this question on the Arduino SE as I believe there are differences in how you would approach this if the problem was on a traditional computer.

Comment: it is not a buffer. only a reference

Comment: Noted, edited the question for clarity.

Comment: nice. now you put the answer into the questions title :-)

Comment: And just like that, it works. Thanks for the magic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your class is only writing to the stream you probably want to have your class take a Print object instead of a Stream object.

The Adafruit library inherits from Print.

Comment: That can change, I only need this line for feedback to either my COM port (Serial) or to the LCD.

Comment: both are derived from Print class. https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/52563/syslogappender-for-log4esp/52575#52575